# How to seccomp a subprocess?

Tags: c++, linux, sandbox, seccomp

I'd like to use `execvp` to create a subprocess and seccomp it (only give it read and write permission, without `open`).
In order to achieve that, I must call seccomp functions *before* `execvp` (which also calls `open`), and thus I should give myself `execvp` and `open` permission. But this also means I give the child process opened by `execvp` such permissions. Is there a way to prevent subprocess to call `open` (e.g. load it to memory before I call seccomp)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cerr << "Starting..." << endl;

    scmp_filter_ctx ctx;
    ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_KILL); // default action: kill

    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(rt_sigreturn), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(exit), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(read), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(write), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(brk), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(mmap), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(munmap), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(mprotect), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(rt_sigprocmask), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(getpid), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(gettid), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(tgkill), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(exit_group), 0);

    // Don't want to give these 3 to child process but execvp requires them
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(open), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(execve), 0);
    seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(access), 0);

    seccomp_load(ctx);

    char * noargv[] = {NULL};

    execvp("./app", noargv);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only allow the specific path and flag

```
char *path = "./app";

// add extra rule for execve
if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(execve), 1, SCMP_A0(SCMP_CMP_NE, (scmp_datum_t)(path))) != 0) {
    return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
}
// do not allow "w" and "rw"
if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(open), 1, SCMP_CMP(1, SCMP_CMP_MASKED_EQ, O_WRONLY, O_WRONLY)) != 0) {
    return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
}
if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, SCMP_SYS(open), 1, SCMP_CMP(1, SCMP_CMP_MASKED_EQ, O_RDWR, O_RDWR)) != 0) {
    return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
}
```

Comment: This is hopelessly insecure, you have blacklisted O_RDWR but not O_CLOEXEC | OR_RDWR. It also checks the value of the pointer, not the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could require a secret random number be passed in the unused syscall arguments.

Comment: Is this a common solution for this problem?